# Django passing arguments to custom method in models (or accessing request)

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to implement some customize login through the custom methods in Django's models. I want to know if its possible to:

- Get request.user in a custom method
- Get the user that made the request in the method
- Or pass an argument to the custom method

Thinking in doing something like this:

```
class OneModel(models.Model):
    (...)

    def viewed(self):
        profile = request.user.profile
        viewed = self.viewed_episodes.filter(user=profile).exists()
        if viewed: return True
        else: return None
```

Another possibility that came to my mind is this:

```
class OneModel(models.Model):
    (...)

    def viewed(self, user):
        profile = user.profile
        viewed = self.viewed_episodes.filter(user=profile).exists()
        if viewed: return True
        else: return None
```

But I think neither of this are possible. Maybe what I need is a template tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second one is correct.

```
def viewed(self, user):
    return self.viewed_episodes.filter(user=user.profile).exists() or None
```

Comment: OK, but then how do I pass the user in the template? Something like {{ instance.viewed user=request.user }} ?? It doesn't work (Error: Could not parse the remainder)

Comment: @anders You should do it in your view, it takes `request` as a first argument.

Comment: OK, I asked wrong then... It should be "Or pass an argument to the custom method in the template"

Comment: @anders Both ways are good. If you want it only for display, you should write a template tag.